# Firebase: Custom Reset Password Action Link

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If I want my server to handle the reset password email action link, what gets sent to my server? I see there's 2 params: `mode` & `oobCode`. What is `mode` going to be and how is `oobCode` used?

Note: this is regarding Firebase's newer "Email Template System". It's not the legacy one with the temporary password in the email body.

Answer (score 0):

`mode` can be one of the following values:

- resetPassword
- recoverEmail
- verifyEmail

and determines which action needs to be handled on your end.

`oobCode`is a one-time code, used to identify and verify the request. You can call the method `firebase.auth.checkActionCode(oobCode)` to verify its validity.

Look the the Firebase docs to see how each `mode` is handled appropriately.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler?hl=en